# Limiting page visit for same IP with php

Tags: php

I have a page, i want so that 1 IP could use the page for lets say 10 times a day at most. 1 refresh = 1 use. After some research i read that this can be done with javascript or php but with cookies. Couldnt the user just delete his cookies and use the page again?
Is there a way to do it only with php and no cookies? Any suggestions?

Note: i am not using any databases.

Comment: then start using databases ... using javascript/cookies only won't do anything, since users can edit both.

Comment: So you need persistent server-side storage and databases are not available? You only have files left. It's difficult to get concurrent file access right, but not impossible.

Comment: `Couldnt the user just delete his cookies and use the page again` - You'll face a similar problem if the user has a dynamic IP

Comment: So, lets say you have a large company where all web access is through a single proxy server. This is very common. So out of the 10,000 users, who would all present the same ip address, you want only 10 of them to be able to access the page per day, or less than 10 of them if one visits it twice?

Comment: @Captain Payalytic .. i gave that number as an example, it wont be 10 ..

Comment: It doesn't matter whether it is 10 or not. The idea that you seem to have is that you can limit a user to a certain number of visits a day by checking what ip address they are visiting from. The point that I am making is that you cannot. I can change the ip address I appear to be coming from and as I said in my previous comment, many many users can and will all appear to be coming from the same address. If you want to limit a user's access, then make the content only available if they are signed in and then limit it from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can't be done without a database. You simply need to keep track of all IPs and you can't do that without a database.

Of course, a simple text file can also go for a database. For every visitor that accesses a certain page, log that IP address to a text file. To see whether they can access the page, just count how many times the IP address is in the file.

Comment: It can't? What about files?

Comment: Files are also kind of database itself :)

Comment: Or just go maybe for SQLite

Answer (score 1):

You can create a database table and then on each view either insert the IP (if its not already in the database) or increment views by 1. If views = 10 don't allow the user to visit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use htaccess file too. But you could write ipaddress/nrofrefreshes records to a text file located on the server.